# Code Contracts vs Code Analyzers

Tags: c#, roslyn, contracts

I'm about to embark on a new C# project. I was wondering what the difference is between using Code Contracts or Code Analyzers (in Roslyn). Am I misunderstanding the usage of each? Being a new project, I would like to maintain the integrity of the code. So I want other developers to adhere to specific code guidelines. I'll research each further, but I was wanting to get the opinion of the community first. Excuse the question, I'm still rather new to C# development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are two different tools.

Code Contracts is a way to declare and check... well, contracts, such as pre-conditions and post-conditions:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(object arg)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(arg != null);
    }

    public object GetBar()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<object>() != null);

        // TODO:
    }
}
```

CC check their conditions at run-time. This requires your *assembly (not source code!)* to be rewritten after compilation to inject appropriate calls into your code.

Code Analyzers use Roslyn to analyze *source code* while you're writing it.
They can help you to format code, to remind you to call `Dispose` on `IDisposable`, and so on, but they don't affect run-time behavior directly.

There are a number of analyzers, grouped by purpose into projects (like [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/Configuration.md)), while [Code Contracts](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts) is a standalone project.

(CC also have static analyzer, but I can't tell much here - it kills performance when used on real projects, so, for me it is usually turned off. Anyway, it is intended to check contracts.)

Comment: thanks for that. So Code Contracts will impact on performance?

Comment: If you want to read up more on Code Contracts, check this ebook https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/csharpcontracts

Comment: @JonMeyers: CC will increase time to build project because of re-writing. At run-time contracts are slower, than `if ... throw`, but I doubt, that you will see the difference in most cases. At the same time, there are significant benefits from using CC.

Answer (score 1):

Code analyzers will analyze your code for common mistakes. They look at the structure of the code and the flow of data across to detect problems.

Another type of analyzers looks at the style (StyleCop for example), capitals, camel casing, prefixes, postfixes and what have you.

The third type are the code contracts you've mentioned, and this works slightly different. You declare the expected behavior of your code, for example what is expected of parameters passed into a method, which exceptions your code can throw etc. The contracts analyzer will then check whether calling code is passing in the right parameters (e.g. the analyzer will detect you passing in null and will raise an error if that's not allowed). At the same time it will check the "internal consistency" of your methods to ensure that you don't throw exceptions you're not allowed to throw. Depending on the implementation contracts can be validated at runtime or at compile time.